# Creating a file on a mounted volume while building a docker container

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to create a file while building a docker container, when I build it I don't get any error and it seems like the file was written correctly, however when I ssh into the container the file is not there.

- I write the file by doing `RUN echo "Some line to add to a file" >> /var/www/public/text.txt` on `Dockerfile`
- My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

  ```
  version: '2'

  services:
  web:
      build: web/
      ports:
          - "8080:80"
      volumes:
          - ./web/:/var/www/
      env_file:
          - web/.env
  ```
- I execute `docker-compose up --build`
- I then do `docker exec -it <container id> bash`
- I `cd` to the folder `/var/www/public` and the file `text.txt` is not there

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volume mounts apply at run time, not during a build. The output of a build is a portable image, not an image and some persistent data you would need to ship separately. That file should exist inside your image, depending on the rest of your Dockerfile.

When you mount a host volume at run time, anything inside the built image is hidden by the host mount. You only see files (along with permissions, uid, and gid) as they exist in the host.

However, if you switch to named volumes, docker will initialize that volume when it's new/empty with the contents of the image at that location.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command in docker-compose.yml file -
version: '2'

```
services:
web:
    build: web/
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./web/:/var/www/
    env_file:
        - web/.env
    command:"echo "Some line to add to a file" >> /var/www/public/text.txt "
```

Since you are mounting the volumes after building the image.

Comment: but I want the file to be created at building time